# Messaging multiple friends privately

Tags: facebook, messaging

Since facebook shut down multiple to: in the send popup (js sdk), I am looking for alternate methods (legitimate fully, FB approved) to send messages to multiple friends at once.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

So far all I've found is XMPP.

Comment: the chat API is what you're looking for http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

Comment: I've already written code to do this (XMPP), and it works.. so so.  What I'm mostly worried about is I log on and fire off messages, then log off. Which is explicitly against the terms of service.